# encrypt postgres column in an update statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, encryption, sql-update

i'm using postgres 9.2 on rhel7 and have started looking at column encryption. I have no problem with getting the encryption to work with an `INSERT` statement, but am failing to work out how to do this with an `UPDATE` statement for a table which already contains rows.

i have been using the example from this URL http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/165-Encrypting-data-with-pgcrypto.html

and my `INSERT` is in the format taken from this URL.

```
INSERT INTO testuserscards(username, cc)
SELECT robotccs.username, pgp_pub_encrypt(robotccs.cc, keys.pubkey) As cc
FROM (VALUES ('robby', '41111111111111111'),
    ('artoo', '41111111111111112') ) As robotccs(username, cc)
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT dearmor('-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
super publickey goobly gook goes here
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----') As pubkey) As keys;
```

i just can't get my head around how the `UPDATE` statement work fit together, i've tried various combinations which look something like the following (different tables used from the `INSERT` above).

```
update dg_test t1 
 set var2 = t2.var2 from (select pgp_pub_encrypt(var1,keys.pubkey) as var2 from dg_test) t2 
 where t1.var1 = t2.var1
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT dearmor('-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
....
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----') As pubkey) As keys;
```

i guess another option would be to build an `ON INSERT` trigger to do the encryption and then run an `DUMP` and `RESTORE`.

has anyone got an idea how to do this with an `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your example, what is the problem with below? (the only difference I join pubkey against original table in the subuery)

```
update dg_test t1 
 set var2 = t2.var2 from (
   select pgp_pub_encrypt(var1,keys.pubkey) as var2 
   from dg_test
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT dearmor('-----BEGIN...--END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----') As pubkey) As keys;
 ) t2 
 where t1.var1 = t2.var1
```